# I want to swap objects keys with new key in javascript. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

I am displaying keypad  from 0 to 9 keys and adding action to it.
EX: 
[keypad display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks1kk.png)

I have keypad array to display keypad:

```
const keypad= [
 {
    symbol: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '2',
    alias: 'abc',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '3',
    alias: 'def',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '4',
    alias: 'ghi',
    checked: false
  }, 
 ......
]
```

When toggle any key, it will add action to it and storing it to redux as object:
Ex: here in this screenshot, I have selected ket 1,2, and 3. My redux object will be like this.

```
const obj1 = {
   "1": {keypadValue:{symbol:"1", alias:undefined},selectedAction:"exit"}
   "2": {keypadValue:{symbol:"2", alias:'abc'},selectedAction:"repeat menu"}',
   "3": {keypadValue:{symbol:"3", alias:'def},selectedAction:"name dialing"}
}
```

Now I want to swap keys: I have selected keys 1,2 and 3. I can swap key with this 3 as well as I can swap with keys those are not selected from keypad. those I can select from dropdown.

I have dropdown[dropdown keypad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx3xi.png)
1. when I click key 1 and choose key 4 from dropdown, I want to swap key 1 with 4. SO in this case key 1 will be unchecked and key 4 will be checked.

2. It can also swap with selected action key: Ex: I can swap key 1 with 2, key 1 with 3 and etc...

If I swap key 1 with key 2 my redux object would be:

```
const obj1 = {
   "2": {keypadValue:{symbol:"2", alias:'abc'},selectedAction:"exit"}
   "1": {keypadValue:{symbol:"1", alias:undefined},selectedAction:"repeat menu"}',
   "3": {keypadValue:{symbol:"3", alias:'def},selectedAction:"name dialing"}
}
```

If I swap Key 2 with 4

object will be:

```
const obj1 = {
   "1": {keypadValue:{symbol:"1", alias:undefined},selectedAction:"exit"}
   "4": {keypadValue:{symbol:"4", alias:'ghi'},selectedAction:"repeat menu"}',
   "3": {keypadValue:{symbol:"3", alias:'def},selectedAction:"name dialing"}
}
```

how can I do this?

I have tried given solution. but it didnt work!!

```
handleRoutingActionKeypadToggle(newKey) {
    const { actions, object } = this.props;
    const { oldKey, keypad } = this.state;

    const updatedKey = manageChangeKeyOption(
      object,
      oldKey,
      newKey,
      keypad
    );

    actions.updateRoutingAction(updatedKey);

    console.log('updatedKey', updatedKey);
  }

export const updateObject = (obj, key, keypad) => {
  const keypadObj = keypad.find(k => k.symbol === key);

  obj.keypadValue = keypadObj;
};

export const manageChangeKeyOption = (
  object,
  oldKey,
  newKey,
  keypad
) => {
  if (object[oldKey.symbol] && object[newKey.symbol]) {
    const oldKeyData = object[newKey.symbol];

    object[oldKey.symbol] = object[newKey.symbol];

    object[newKey.symbol] = oldKeyData;
    updateObject(
      object[oldKey.symbol],
      oldKey.symbol,
      keypad
    );

    updateObject(object[newKey.symbol], newKey.symbol, keypad);

    return object;
  } else if (object[oldKey.symbol]) {
    object[newKey.symbol] = object[oldKey.symbol];
    updateObject(object[newKey.symbol], newKey.symbol, keypad);
    delete object[oldKey.symbol];

    return object;
  }
};
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qbhj.png)

Comment: Hello @Komal is there any mistake in the output object you need, as the alias seems to not change, or is it what you want?

Comment: I want to change entire key with value. I forget to update alias in above example/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this snippet? This should work for you

```js
const keypad= [
 {
    symbol: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '2',
    alias: 'abc',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '3',
    alias: 'def',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '4',
    alias: 'ghi',
    checked: false
  }
]
const obj1 = {
   "1": {keypadValue:{symbol:"1", alias:undefined},selectedAction:"exit"},
   "2": {keypadValue:{symbol:"2", alias:'abc'},selectedAction:"repeat menu"},
   "3": {keypadValue:{symbol:"3", alias:'def'},selectedAction:"name dialing"}
}
function updatePosition(oldKey, newKey){
 if(obj1[oldKey] && obj1[newKey]){
     //swap keys
        let oldKeyData = obj1[oldKey];
        obj1[oldKey] = obj1[newKey];
        obj1[newKey] = oldKeyData;
        updateObject(obj1[oldKey], oldKey);
        updateObject(obj1[newKey], newKey);
    }else{
     if(obj1[oldKey]){
         obj1[newKey] = obj1[oldKey];
            updateObject(obj1[newKey], newKey);
            delete obj1[oldKey];
        }else{
         //this is new insert to list
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}
function updateObject(obj, key){
   let keypadObj = keypad.find(k => k.symbol == key);
    obj.keypadValue = keypadObj;
}
console.log(updatePosition(1,2));
console.log(updatePosition(1,4));
```

Comment: Thanks!! @Jeethesh!! I actually need return updated object  that I can update in store. I added helper functions, but not sure what value should I return.

Comment: @KomalKanpariya you can always return the object. Updated the snippet check now

Comment: What is the operation you are executing on manageChangeKeyOption?  And can you show console of object, oldKey, newKey,keypad

Comment: @KomalKanpariya great. Can you please mark this as the correct answer as it solved your problem